# Несколько картинок в посте. Как организовать?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

Пишу RoR приложение с блогом. В каждом блоге может быть несколько картинок. Количество картинок неизвестно.

Для загрузки изображений собираюсь использовать paperclip.

Все пример, которые я находил привязывают к записи одну картинку, причем это поле модели.

Как организовать модель или набор моделей чтоб в одном блоге могло отображаться несколько картинок? И как это организовать при написании блога через markdown разметку.

Дайте, пожалуйста, или ссылки на примеры, или расскажите как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как организовать модель или набор моделей чтоб в одном блоге могло
>   отображаться несколько картинок? И как это организовать при написании
>   блога через markdown разметку.

Вам нужно создать отдельную модель для картинок

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end
```

ну и добавить соответствующие миграции http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#svyaz-has_many